# Uploading multiple files to firebase storage

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload multiple images at once to **Firebase Storage**.
Unfortunately the images are doubled when uploaded, i.e, when I upload **2** images I found **4 to 10** images in the bucket.
The code in the image is what I used.

[image]

Comment: You haven't provided the code, but before you do, don't upload it as an image.  Copy the code into the question and format it as code, which will make it easier to read and search.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You should check out [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good well-received question

Comment: This is not good way how you ask question and provide code in image attachment. Please post code as text to help others to look into it and provide some edited code back as solution.